# Sheets quota limits

Tags: google-sheets, quota

I am currently having an issue with the quota limits in the sheets application and am in need of help linking my account to a cloud project extending this quota.

To be more specific.  I have an application that is recording to a sheets document.  In some cases up to 5000 rows within a couple minutes.  Because of the quota this shuts down within a couple seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code? Perhaps you are sending requests too quickly? Can you share your error message? Maybe the (batchUpdate)[https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate] endpoint would help you? That is, if its a question of sending too many requests or making too many to quickly

Comment: I am sending too quickly.  I am sending through a data connector in tray.io.  Tray processes all requests simultaneously.  The only solve I have found on this is to delay sending each by a random number of seconds.  Message is that I hit the sheets quota.

Comment: I'm not sure how tray.io works, but it sounds like you need to group your requests together somehow before sending them. How is the tray.io side implemented?

Comment: Tray receives a webhook post for each order creation, then posts that data to sheets. Since these are all individual requests they can not be grouped for one large data post.